# Servlet @WebServlet urlPatterns

Tags: java, servlets, url-pattern

This is a quick question but I couldn't find a quick answer. 
Now I have a servlet BaseServlet, 
when user request any of the url below:

```
host
host/
host/BaseServlet
```

It should always refer to the same servlet and redirect to the homepage.

When I set

```
@WebServlet({"/BaseServlet", ""})
```

Only

```
host/
host/BaseServlet
```

works

If I set

```
@WebServlet({"/BaseServlet", "", "/"})
```

The BaseServlet will be requested constantly in loop ...

Why?

Edit: 
BaseServlet does a forward to the index.html hid in WEB-INF folder and that's it.

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.html").forward(request,response);
```

The servlet spec says "A string containing only the / character indicates the "default" servlet of the application." So I want the BaseServlet to be my default. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you do with the response?

Comment: Do some pre-processing, and then response with a webpage.

Comment: That webpage might be making the servlet re-execute in the loop you spoke about. Show us.

Answer (score 12):

1. As you state in your Q, if you want the following:

   ```
   host/
   host/BaseServlet
   ```

   Use

   ```
   @WebServlet({"/BaseServlet", ""})
   ```
2. If you want the following:

   ```
   host
   ```

   Add this to your welcome file (you can't specifiy welcome files using annotations)

   ```
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>/BaseServlet</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```
3. > The servlet spec says *"A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application."*

   But it says straight afterwards

   > *In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
   >   and the path info is null.*

   In other words, if your URL is

   ```
   host
   ```

   then the servlet path will be

   ```
   "" (empty string)
   ```

   so you will need a welcome file list (but index.htm[l] and index.jsp in the webapp directory, not WEB-INF, are included implicitly as a starting welcome file list)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

If you want to pre-process then you can use Filter with url-pattern "/*" and dispatcher set to REQUEST that way it will ignore forward.

Last value "/" means all request.

Checkout discussion at: http://www.coderanch.com/t/366340/Servlets/java/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

And inside Servlet another forward request for index.html is generated which is also intercepted by servlet.

If you try @WebServlet({"/BaseServlet", "/"}) which is same as @WebServlet({"/BaseServlet", "", "/"}) will result in same error.

You can check this by typing following output statement in servlet:

```
System.out.println(req.getRequestURL());
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't reply in time but I don't really understand what you are saying. The servlet spec says "A string containing only the / character indicates the "default" servlet of the application." So I want the BaseServlet to be my default. Why it doesn't work?