# Defining java servlet as a main web page - servlet annotations not working

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet has this annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Download", urlPatterns = {"/download"})
public class Download extends HttpServlet {
....
```

And its working like expected. But I want to set this servlet as main web page. So I defined in `web.xml` file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Download</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And it does not work, page not found. So the solution I found is:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xsistema.........Download</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Download</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Download</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

And now the page is found. But why its not enough only annotations without mapping it at `web.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
@WebServlet(name = "Download", urlPatterns = {"/download"})
```

to

```
@WebServlet(name = "Download", urlPatterns = {"/download", ""})
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578694/servlet-webservlet-urlpatterns).